# Raspberry Pi Zero with Ethernet Over HDMI

Tags: hdmi, ethernet, connection, pi-zero

The new Raspberry Pi Zero doesn't have any kind of wired Ethernet connection. Has anyone have tested if Ethernet over HDMI works? I did not find any info in the web or even what version of HDMI the Raspberry Pi Zero uses.

Comment: You should be able to use a USB Ethernet adapter

Comment: Yea, but the point is Ethernet over HDMI... I wonder if its even possible. That would just be amazing. If they missed that then they really messed up :(

Comment: The SoC doesn't support it, so it's a no go

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**No, the Pi Zero does not support ethernet over HDMI.**

Unfortunately the schematics for the Pi Zero are not available (edited: an overview schematics is available now, see updated information below). However since it is essentially an minimized Pi 1 I'd bet that the HDMI circuitry is (nearly) the same - though the Pi 1 features a standard sized HDMI connector (Type A) whereas the Pi Zero comes with a mini connector (Type C).

Looking at the [schematics of Model A and B (Type 1) Revision 2.1 on Github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/documentation/eef7dcdb9c48c02274983cb3618dc8a8de8894d0/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf) or [on webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925200244/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf) ([Raspberrypi.org's schematics](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#schematics-and-mechanical-drawings) are now downgraded to less detail), page 2, we find that the pin 14 at the HDMI connector is not connected. This pin is responsible for the HDMI-Ethernet-Channel (HEC) for HDMI 1.4 and reserved for HDMI 1.0-1.3. So there's no HDMI ethernet connected on the Pi.

Pin 14 (reserved for HEC) on the Type A connector corresponds to pin 17 on a Type C connector, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Connectors). The [overview schematics of the Pi Zero 1.3](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528145041/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-V1.3-Schematics.pdf) shows this pin as *not connected* (thanks to user Wilf for pointing to this updated information).

---

<sup>On a side note: Two facts support the notion that there is no HEC on the Pi Zero - there is no dedicated ethernet controller on the board (such as the LAN9512 for the B/B+/2B Pi) and to be honest, if the Pi Zero would support HEC, the Foundation would have announced it as such! It's just not a feature that you hide.</sup>

Comment: The Raspberry Pi forums agree with you. From 2012: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6378&p=243457

Comment: @Ghanima Are the schematics not available *yet* or *at all*? Could it be, even though Zero is minimized Pi1, that it has the pin connected and supports the ethernet over HDMI? This would be great for a board that doesn't have ethernet port by default - size is minimized, but functionality not.

Comment: @Asunez, I do not know whether or when the Foundation will make the schematics available (e.g. schematics for Pi2 are not avaible). Concerning the existence of HEC on the Pi Zero. As I stated it I guess that it is highly unprobable. Two facts support that: there is no dedicated ethernet controller on the board (such as the LAN9512 for the B/B+/2B Pi and to be honest, if the Pi Zero would support HEC, they would have announced it as such! It's just not a feature that you hide.

Comment: The link (for some reason was removed) now appears to need be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/documentation/eef7dcdb9c48c02274983cb3618dc8a8de8894d0/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf (or https://web.archive.org/web/20150925200244/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf). However in the zero's 1.3 schematic the pin shows as connected to *something* https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-V1.3-Schematics.pdf

Comment: @Wilf thanks for the update! (edited accordingly) Note that the mini connector and the standard connector have different pinouts - HEC is not connected though.