# RPi zero ethernet connection via HDMI port using a HDMI to RJ45 adaptor

Tags: hdmi, ethernet, pi-zero, ethernet-port

I would like to connect the Raspberry Pi Zero to my laptop using an ethernet cable without using the micro-USB port. Currently I can connect using ethernet cable through a micro-USB to RJ45 converter. I am using Putty and xming for the GUI. 
For our project we have a limitation of not using a powered USB hub and we need a UMTS stick for 3G connected all the time to the Rpi. Hence I cannot use it for ethernet connection.
**So is it possible to use the free micro HDMI port using a HDMI to Rj45 adaptor to connect an ethernet cable to Rpi Zero ?**

Comment: Related (if you do not mean the HDMI range extender covered in goobering's answer): http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38650/raspberry-pi-zero-with-ethernet-over-hdmi

Comment: yeah I had a look at that thread earlier. I wanted to run Putty SSH using a HDMI to RJ45 adaptor. So i guess that wont work?

Comment: No, I guess not.

Comment: There is no micro HDMI port on the Raspberry Pi Zero. It is a mini HDMI port.

Answer (score 9):

No. HDMI to Ethernet adapters are used to send HDMI display data over an Ethernet cable, rather than network data over HDMI. This won't work.

Comment: [HDMI 1.4 has an Ethernet channel (HEC) built into the cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4), but is [not supported on the Raspberry Pi Zero](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38650/raspberry-pi-zero-with-ethernet-over-hdmi)

Comment: @RonBeyer that would be awesome if you made it an answer and fleshed it out more.

Comment: @goobering please update your answer with sources or edit for accuracy.  Right now, your answer is not correct and lacks sufficient resolution to explain yourself.