# Streaming offline

Tags: camera, streaming-video, pi-zero

I want to buy a Raspberry Pi Zero and put it outside my home. I want to stream it's camera input to my Raspberry Pi B at home and somehow put it onto a website and I can't connect rpi zero to wifi. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38622/whats-the-cheapest-way-to-get-network-connectivity-to-the-pi-zero "streaming and offline" makes little sense to me. If streaming is needed, some connectivity is highly desirable ;) Be it WiFi, ethernet or some other kind of serial connection (think UART with RS485 transcievers).

Comment: Also worth noting: the pi-zero does not have a camera connector on it. You would have to use the usb interface or GPIO.