# Ethernet options for streaming video from a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: ethernet, pi-zero, streaming-video

I am streaming video from multiple Pi zero WHs, via ethernet, to a master Pi 3B+ which saves the streams to a hard drive. I chose Pi zeros due to their low cost and low power draw (I'm running from battery), and ethernet for low latency and high reliability over a UDP connection. But I haven't come up with a great way to actually implement the ethernet connection.

The options I'm aware of are:

- **Micro-USB to RJ45 Adaptor** [[1]](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2015-New-arrival-Micro-5pin-USB-To-RJ45-10-100M-Ethernet-Network-Adapter-For-SamsungTable-PC/32368226383.html) - Seems great in theory but I've read that many of these AliExpress adaptors have bandwidths orders of magnitude lower than advertised, which could be an issue for video streaming.
- **Micro-USB OTG Adaptor & USB to RJ45 Adaptor (Male-Female)** [[2]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D8YZ2SA) [[3]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ET4KHJ2) - This is what I'm using now and it works, but it feels a bit cludgy with how many cables and connections it involves
- **Micro-USB OTG Adaptor & USB to RJ45 Adaptor (Male-Male)** [[2]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D8YZ2SA) [[4]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KMRVGFO) - Well-reviewed, but I can't find any similar products rated for more than 500kbaud--too slow for video streaming

Other notes:

- The first two options come from [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38641/105065) helpful existing answer
- I'm working with a ~2.5MBps minimum bandwidth to accommodate my video streams
- I'll be hooking up upwards of 12 cameras, so I'd like to keep cost down, if possible

Comment: [4] is a serial cable - so, forget that - you say you need 2.5MBps ... in other words 20 megabits/second? or did you mean 2.5Mbps (note the b instead of the B) - if you did mean 20megabits/second .. that's 240 over 12 cameras ... and the pi3B+ will struggle with that

Comment: @JaromandaX I can definitely switch to a beefier master unit if I need to, but I've seen anywhere from [20MBps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146444) to [50MBps](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146444) write speeds cited on the 3B+, and I don't expect my gstreamer filesinks to be computationally taxing beyond the writing itself--so I figured I'd at least give it a try.

Comment: really? 160 to 400 megabits per second ethernet on a 3B+? Due to USB2.0 it's limited to 330mbit and real world you get less than that, so, not sure where your 400mbit is coming from

Comment: @JaromandaX I think the theoretical limit for USB2.0 is 480Mbps (per the [USB2.0 spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0)), so 400 is possible and 240 seems doable. Thanks for the heads-up, though; I'll be sure to do some testing to make sure I can do it in practice.

Comment: Yeah, I know the spec is 480, but the documentation for the 3+ states that the limit **is** 330 ... maybe that's the "real world" figure based on the theoretical limit. Sorry to take you off track so much though. In my opinion, although it's "cludgy" I think your current solution is probably the best